# FetchXML or condition on the attributes of two related entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

The requirements for this FetchXML statement are:

- Return all 'ebs_opportunityinternshipunit' where

  - 'createdon' is 'last-week'
  - and

    - 'owner' of 'account' is 'eq-userid'

      - 'account' is referenced by 'parentaccountid' of 'opportunity'
    - or
    - 'owner' of 'account2' is 'eq-userid'

      - 'account2' is referenced by 'mitacs_partner2' of 'opportunity'

I've tried configuring the filter with out-of-the-box tools, XRMToolbox FetchXML Builder, visiting the official CRM Community forum, and reading FetchXML documentation. Still, the best that I've been able to come up with is below:

```
<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical">
   <entity name="ebs_opportunityinternshipunit">
      <attribute name="ebs_name" />
      <attribute name="createdon" />
      <attribute name="ebs_opportunityinternshipunitid" />
      <order attribute="ebs_name" descending="false" />
      <filter type="and">
         <condition attribute="createdon" operator="last-week" />
         <filter type="or">
            <condition entityname="ab" attribute="ownerid" operator="eq-userid" />
            <condition entityname="ac" attribute="ownerid" operator="eq-userid" />
         </filter>
      </filter>
      <link-entity name="opportunity" from="opportunityid" to="ebs_opportunity" link-type="inner" alias="aa">
         <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentaccountid" link-type="inner" alias="ab" />
         <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="mitacs_partner2" link-type="inner" alias="ac" />
      </link-entity>
   </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: FetchXML doesn't support filtering across multiple entities. Where are you trying to use this FetchXML? Is it in custom code?

Comment: Could you provide the relationship between the entities specially between,
ebs_opportunityinternshipunit
opportunity
account (it seems its connected to custom entity with two different relationship)

also it will be helpful to show expected output of data and what are you receiving

Comment: @aron This is custom FetchXML but I'd like it to operate as the filter for a View. I've done this before. You have to export a solution, put the custom FetchXML in the correct place, and import the solution.

Comment: @chowdhury ebs_opportunityunit has a N:1 relationship with opportunity, opportunity has a N:1 relationship with account. What I want returned is all ebs_opportunityunits where the ebs_opportunityunit's opportunity's account's owner is the current user. The actual requirements are more complicated but once I can do that, I can do whatever I need to do. Also, I've heard that multiple FetchXML statements can be combined in FetchXML. Could these achieve the result that I am looking for?

Comment: You might need to set those `account` link entities to **outer**

Comment: Thanks. FetchXML does not allow unions within a query. Perhaps the Outer join will help. If not, you may have to add data to enable you to query with FetchXML. For example, perhaps create an "Account Owners" linking entity to associate the Account Owner to the Opportunity Unit. You could potentially use an OOB Flow or workflow to populate it, though, depending on the complexity it may require custom code to keep it in sync, which would mean custom workflow or plugin.